React generic table server-side pagination problem
I want to create generic react table to use in my project. I prefer tanstack table and add server-side pagination. After changing pagesize, frontend get data from server, but rerender page with default pagesize. How do I make to prevent rerendering of the table?
function ReactTable({
  endpointsKey,
  endpointsKey2,
  columns,
  filter: parentFilter,
  modalToggler,
  expandingDetailComponent: ExpandingDetailComponent,
  filterComponent: FilterComponent
}) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const matchDownSM = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(null);
  const [filterExpanded, setFilterExpanded] = useState(false);

  const { onPaginationChange, pagination } = usePagination();
  const { pageIndex, pageSize } = pagination;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (parentFilter) setFilter(parentFilter);
  }, [parentFilter]);

  const {
    list: data,
    totalElements,
    totalPages,
    loading,
    error,
    validating,
    empty
  } = useGetItem({
    endpointsKey,
    endpointsKey2,
    filter,
    pageIndex: pageIndex,
    pageSize: pageSize
  });

  const isLoader = loading || data === undefined;
  const loader = (
    <Box sx={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 310px)' }}>
      <CircularLoader />
    </Box>
  );

  function getPageCount() {
    return totalPages;
  }

  const openFilterComponent = () => {
    setFilterExpanded(!filterExpanded);
  };
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState([
    {
      id: 'id',
      desc: true
    }
  ]);
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState({});
  const [globalFilter, setGlobalFilter] = useState('');

  columns = columns.filter((columns) => !columns.disabled);

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    state: {
      sorting,
      rowSelection,
      globalFilter,
      pagination: pagination,
      pageCount: getPageCount()
    },
    enableRowSelection: true,
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    onGlobalFilterChange: setGlobalFilter,
    getRowCanExpand: () => true,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
    globalFilterFn: fuzzyFilter,
    manualPagination: true,
    onPaginationChange: onPaginationChange,
    debugTable: true
  });

  const backColor = alpha(theme.palette.primary.lighter, 0.1);
  let headers = [];
  columns.map(
    (columns) =>
   

      columns.accessorKey &&
      headers.push({
        label: typeof columns.header === 'string' ? columns.header : '#',
        // @ts-ignore
        key: columns.accessorKey
      })
  );

  if (!data?.length && error) return <EmptyTable msg="No Data" />;

  return (    <MainCard content={false}>
      {isLoader || !data?.length || error ? (
        loader
      ) : (<Table> ...</Table>)}
  </MainCard>
  );
}`

